# Microsoft Graph API appCatalogs/teamsApps fails when using application credential

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We found that the API appCatalogs/teamsApp (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/appcatalogs-list-teamsapps) stopped working when use application credential. It was working fine a few days ago. We checked and ensured that we have assigned sufficient permissions according to the document. By comparison, when use password credential with delegate permissions, this API works.

Not sure if this a temporary issue, or there is some change.

Also noticed that the error messages are not consistent between tests. Sometimes it says
`Failed to execute Aad backend request GetTenantSubscribedSkusRequest`, and sometimes it returns `Failed to execute Aad backend request GetUserLicensesRequest`. Here is one example of the response in a Postman test including the error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Exception in GetUserAggregatedAppsAsync., UserId: '88fe7d3c-f489-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.ServiceException: Failed to execute Aad backend request GetUserLicensesRequest. Workload Unknown. Request Url: https://graph.windows.net/4ed49f23-73c9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/users/88fe7d3c-f489-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/licenseDetails?api-version=1.6, Request Method: GET, Response Status Code: Unauthorized, Response Headers: ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: khPOVZXWnH8D7cYi/jPTse34lSXOYF4VeaGgIR3yMUA=\r\nrequest-id: b67895eb-6f86-4b16-8cc7-9ab890fbce6a\r\nclient-request-id: 6bf652e8-19af-446e-ba74-4cc2df669b47\r\nStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains\r\nDate: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 14:24:00 GMT\r\n, Reason Phrase: Unauthorized\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.HandleErrorResponseAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, String piiScrubbedRequestUrl, StringBuilder rawHeadersBuilder, IPerfTracker tracker) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 434\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteHttpRequestAsync>d__41.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 373\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__38.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 176\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.ServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\Requests\\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.AADService.<GetUserLicenseDetails>d__63.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\AADService.cs:line 1430\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.AADService.<GetUserLicenseDetails>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\AADService.cs:line 89\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Provider.Utilities.UserLicenseAndTenantSettingsManager.<GetApplicableSkuCategoriesForUser>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\Provider\\Provider\\Utilities\\UserLicenseAndTenantSettingsManager.cs:line 451\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.InstrumentedAsyncFunc`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\Common\\Common\\InstrumentedAsyncFunc.cs:line 118\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.ServiceException: Failed to execute Aad backend request GetUserLicensesRequest. Workload Unknown. Request Url: https://graph.windows.net/4ed49f23-73c9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/users/88fe7d3c-f489-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/licenseDetails?api-version=1.6, Request Method: GET, Response Status Code: Unauthorized, Response Headers: ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: khPOVZXWnH8D7cYi/jPTse34lSXOYF4VeaGgIR3yMUA=\r\nrequest-id: b67895eb-6f86-4b16-8cc7-9ab890fbce6a\r\nclient-request-id: 6bf652e8-19af-446e-ba74-4cc2df669b47\r\nStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains\r\nDate: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 14:24:00 GMT\r\n, Reason Phrase: Unauthorized\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.HandleErrorResponseAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, String piiScrubbedRequestUrl, StringBuilder rawHeadersBuilder, IPerfTracker tracker) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 434\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteHttpRequestAsync>d__41.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 373\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__38.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 176\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.ServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\Requests\\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.AADService.<GetUserLicenseDetails>d__63.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\AADService.cs:line 1430\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.AADService.<GetUserLicenseDetails>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\AADService.cs:line 89\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Provider.Utilities.UserLicenseAndTenantSettingsManager.<GetApplicableSkuCategoriesForUser>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\Provider\\Provider\\Utilities\\UserLicenseAndTenantSettingsManager.cs:line 451\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.InstrumentedAsyncFunc`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\Common\\Common\\InstrumentedAsyncFunc.cs:line 118<---\r\nOne or more errors occurred.",
        "innerError": {
            "message": "Exception in GetUserAggregatedAppsAsync., UserId: '88fe7d3c-f489-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.ServiceException: Failed to execute Aad backend request GetUserLicensesRequest. Workload Unknown. Request Url: https://graph.windows.net/4ed49f23-73c9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/users/88fe7d3c-f489-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/licenseDetails?api-version=1.6, Request Method: GET, Response Status Code: Unauthorized, Response Headers: ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: khPOVZXWnH8D7cYi/jPTse34lSXOYF4VeaGgIR3yMUA=\r\nrequest-id: b67895eb-6f86-4b16-8cc7-9ab890fbce6a\r\nclient-request-id: 6bf652e8-19af-446e-ba74-4cc2df669b47\r\nStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains\r\nDate: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 14:24:00 GMT\r\n, Reason Phrase: Unauthorized\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.HandleErrorResponseAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, String piiScrubbedRequestUrl, StringBuilder rawHeadersBuilder, IPerfTracker tracker) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 434\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteHttpRequestAsync>d__41.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 373\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__38.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 176\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.ServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\Requests\\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.AADService.<GetUserLicenseDetails>d__63.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\AADService.cs:line 1430\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.AADService.<GetUserLicenseDetails>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\AADService.cs:line 89\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Provider.Utilities.UserLicenseAndTenantSettingsManager.<GetApplicableSkuCategoriesForUser>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\Provider\\Provider\\Utilities\\UserLicenseAndTenantSettingsManager.cs:line 451\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.InstrumentedAsyncFunc`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\Common\\Common\\InstrumentedAsyncFunc.cs:line 118\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.ServiceException: Failed to execute Aad backend request GetUserLicensesRequest. Workload Unknown. Request Url: https://graph.windows.net/4ed49f23-73c9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/users/88fe7d3c-f489-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/licenseDetails?api-version=1.6, Request Method: GET, Response Status Code: Unauthorized, Response Headers: ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: khPOVZXWnH8D7cYi/jPTse34lSXOYF4VeaGgIR3yMUA=\r\nrequest-id: b67895eb-6f86-4b16-8cc7-9ab890fbce6a\r\nclient-request-id: 6bf652e8-19af-446e-ba74-4cc2df669b47\r\nStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains\r\nDate: Fri, 03 Jun 2022 14:24:00 GMT\r\n, Reason Phrase: Unauthorized\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.HandleErrorResponseAsync(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, String piiScrubbedRequestUrl, StringBuilder rawHeadersBuilder, IPerfTracker tracker) in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 434\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteHttpRequestAsync>d__41.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 373\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.CommonServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__38.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\CommonServiceRequestBase.cs:line 176\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.ServiceRequestBase`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\Requests\\ServiceRequestBase.cs:line 0\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.AADService.<GetUserLicenseDetails>d__63.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\AADService.cs:line 1430\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.BackendServices.AAD.AADService.<GetUserLicenseDetails>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\BackendServices\\BackendServices\\AAD\\AADService.cs:line 89\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Provider.Utilities.UserLicenseAndTenantSettingsManager.<GetApplicableSkuCategoriesForUser>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\Provider\\Provider\\Utilities\\UserLicenseAndTenantSettingsManager.cs:line 451\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.SkypeSpaces.MiddleTier.Common.InstrumentedAsyncFunc`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in D:\\a\\_work\\1\\s\\Source\\Common\\Common\\InstrumentedAsyncFunc.cs:line 118<---\r\nOne or more errors occurred.",
            "code": "AccessDenied",
            "innerError": {},
            "date": "2022-06-03T14:24:00",
            "request-id": "9f09d8dc-8be3-4793-9fa1-2d160553724e",
            "client-request-id": "9f09d8dc-8be3-4793-9fa1-2d160553724e"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested in Application permission and it seem to work

[image]

Comment: I tested and it is working now. It seems that the issue has been resolved on Microsoft side.